# socket.username keeps displaying as udefined on my clinet html

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to build a chatroom in node.js and socket.io but when i try to display the users name beside their message it just shows undefined here is my client code

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
<meta name="description" content="BillIsChill-2.0 BETA">
<meta name="keywords" content="billischill,Bill,is,chill,2.0,billischill-2.0,gamer-chat,BillIsChill-Underground-Chat,BILLISCHILL,>
<meta name="author" content="Nik Hendricks">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <title>BillIsChill-2.0</title>
    <link type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" href="http://billischill.ddns.net/billischill-2.0/css/masterStyle.css" />
    <link type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" href="http://billischill.ddns.net/billischill-2.0/css/animate.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main-header-div">
      <p id="main-header-div-text">BillIsChill-2.0<p>
        <form>
            <input id="main-header-div-search-txtinpt" class="search" placeholder="Search" name="search"/>
        </form>
    </div>
      <div id="sidebar-controls-div">
           <div id="sidebar-homebutton">
                     <div class="sidebar-control-img" id="sidebar-homebutton-img">
                     </div>
           </div>
                      <div id="Chatrooms-sidebar-button" class="sidebar-control-button">
                        <div class="sidebar-control-img" id="sidebar-chatroombutton-img">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                   <div id="avatar-sidebar-button" class="sidebar-control-button">
                        <div class="sidebar-control-img" id="sidebar-avatarbutton-img">
                        </div>
                   </div>

        </div>


     <div id="chat-rooms-div" class="main-div">
            <div id="rooms">
            </div>
     </div>
     <div id="chat-box-div" class="main-div">
     <div id="chatlog-display-div">

    </div>
    <form id="chatform" action="">
        <hr id="chat-box-div-hr">
        <div id="chat-controls-div">
        <input id="chat-box-div-txtinpt" class="big-txtinpt"type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Message">
        <input id="chat-box-div-submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="online-users-div">
<div>
    <script>


    var socket = io();

    socket.on('connect', function(){
        socket.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
    });
    socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
        $('#chatlog-display-div').append(username + data);
    });
    socket.on('welcomeuser', function(data, username){
        jQuery("#chatlog-display-div").append(data + username);
    });
    socket.on('updaterooms', function(rooms, current_room) {
        $('#rooms').empty();
        $.each(rooms, function(key, value) {
            if(value == current_room){
                $('#rooms').append('<div id="chatroom-box"><center>' + value + '<center></div><hr>');
                $("#chatlog-display-div").scrollTop($("#chatlog-display-div").prop("scrollHeight"));
            }
            else {
                $('#rooms').append('<div id="chatroom-box"><center><a id="chatroom-box-link" href="#" onclick="switchRoom(\''+value+'\')">' + value + '</a></center></div><hr>');
                $("#chatlog-display-div").scrollTop($("#chatlog-display-div").prop("scrollHeight"));
            }
        });
    });
    function switchRoom(room){
        socket.emit('switchRoom', room);
    }




     $('form').submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();




   //right here is were i started changin it

           //gets the value from the message text feild and sets it as the    message var
     var message = {
            text : $('#chat-box-div-txtinpt').val()
            }
        if (message.text.trim().length !== 0) {
                        socket.emit('chat-message',message);
                //append the message to the chatlog-display-div
                $('#chat-box-div-txtinpt').focus().val('');
                jQuery("#chatlog-display-div").append('<div><b>'+socket.username+':</b>&nbsp'+message.text+'</div><hr>');
                            $("#chatlog-display-div").scrollTop($("#chatlog-display-div").prop("scrollHeight"));
            }
                        });
          socket.on('chat-message', function (message) {
           jQuery("#chatlog-display-div").append('<div><b>'+socket.name+':</b>&nbsp'+message.text+'</div><hr>');
                         $("#chatlog-display-div").scrollTop($("#chatlog-display-div").prop("scrollHeight"));
          });

              var something = document.getElementById('sidebar-homebutton');

              something.style.cursor = 'pointer';
              something.onclick = function() {
              window.location.href = "http://billischill.ddns.net";

               };

    </script>
```

and here is my server code

index.js

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var usernames = {};
var rooms = ['General-Chat','Tech-Chat','Gamer-Chat',"BillIsChill-Underground-Chat","Programer-Chat","Hacker-Chat","Minecraft-Chat","Gta-Chat","Misc-Chat","Current-Events-Chat"];



app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
  //res.sendfile('/login/');
});
 http.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:8080');
});

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
    database: "messages"
 });
 io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('adduser', function(username){
    socket.username = username;
    socket.room = 'General-Chat';
    usernames[username] = username;
    socket.join('General-Chat');
    socket.broadcast.to('General-Chat').emit('updatechat', '<b class="servertxt">SERVER: </b>', socket.username + ' has connected to this room' + '<hr>');
    socket.emit('welcomeuser', '<b class="servertxt">SERVER:</b> Welcome ', socket.username + '<hr>');
    socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, 'room1');
});
socket.on('switchRoom', function(newroom){
  socket.leave(socket.room);
  socket.join(newroom);
  socket.emit('updatechat', '<b class="servertxt"> SERVER </b>', 'you have connected to '+ newroom + '<hr>');
  // sent message to OLD room
  socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('updatechat', '<b class="servertxt">  SERVER </b>', socket.username+' has left this room <hr>');
  // update socket session room title
  socket.room = newroom;
  socket.broadcast.to(newroom).emit('updatechat', '<b class="servertxt"> SERVER </b>', socket.username+' has joined this room <hr>');
  socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, newroom);
 });
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    // remove the username from global usernames list
    delete usernames[socket.username];
    // update list of users in chat, client-side
    io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
    socket.leave(socket.room);
});
  socket.on('chat-message', function (message) {
     console.log('message:', socket.username+': ' + message.text);

 var insert = { roomName: socket.room, username: socket.username, message: message.text };

 //puts message in db
 con.query('INSERT INTO messages SET ?', insert, function(err,res){
  if(err) throw err;

  console.log('Last insert ID:', res.insertId);
});
 //excludes "socket" from getting the emit
      socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit("chat-message", message);
  });
});
```

Can somone please help me  i am very confused on what is happening here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client code has some minor bugs, I would try to make some changes,

server.js:

```
socket.on('chat-message', function (user, message) {
   console.log('message:', user + ': ' + message.text);
   var insert = { roomName: socket.room, username: user, message: message.text };
   //puts message in db
   con.query('INSERT INTO messages SET ?', insert, function(err,res){
    if(err) throw err;
      console.log('Last insert ID:', res.insertId);
    });
   //excludes "socket" from getting the emit
   socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit("chat-message", user, message);
  });
```

in the client:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
        <meta name="description" content="BillIsChill-2.0 BETA"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="billischill,Bill,is,chill,2.0,billischill-2.0,gamer-chat,BillIsChill-Underground-Chat,BILLISCHILL"/>
        <meta name="author" content="Nik Hendricks">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <title>BillIsChill-2.0</title>
        <link type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" href="http://billischill.ddns.net/billischill-2.0/css/masterStyle.css" />
        <link type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" href="http://billischill.ddns.net/billischill-2.0/css/animate.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="main-header-div">
          <p id="main-header-div-text">BillIsChill-2.0<p>
            <form>
              <input id="main-header-div-search-txtinpt" class="search" placeholder="Search" name="search"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar-controls-div">
          <div id="sidebar-homebutton">
            <div class="sidebar-control-img" id="sidebar-homebutton-img">   </div>
          </div>
        <div id="Chatrooms-sidebar-button" class="sidebar-control-button">
          <div class="sidebar-control-img" id="sidebar-chatroombutton-img"></div>
        </div>
          <div id="avatar-sidebar-button" class="sidebar-control-button">
            <div class="sidebar-control-img" id="sidebar-avatarbutton-img"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="chat-rooms-div" class="main-div">
          <div id="rooms"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="chat-box-div" class="main-div">
          <div id="chatlog-display-div"></div>
          <form id="chatform" action="">
          <hr id="chat-box-div-hr">
          <div id="chat-controls-div">
            <input id="chat-box-div-txtinpt" class="big-txtinpt"type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Message">
            <input id="chat-box-div-submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="online-users-div"><div>

      <script>
        var socket = io();

        socket.on('connect', function() {
            var user = prompt("What's your name?");
            socket.username = user;
            socket.emit('adduser', user);
        });

        socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
            $('#chatlog-display-div').append(username + data);
        });

        socket.on('welcomeuser', function(data, username){
            jQuery("#chatlog-display-div").append(data + username);
        });

        socket.on('updaterooms', function(rooms, current_room) {
            $('#rooms').empty();
            $.each(rooms, function(key, value) {
                if(value == current_room){
                    $('#rooms').append('<div id="chatroom-box"><center>' + value + '<center></div><hr>');
                    $("#chatlog-display-div").scrollTop($("#chatlog-display-div").prop("scrollHeight"));
                }
                else {
                    $('#rooms').append('<div id="chatroom-box"><center><a id="chatroom-box-link" href="#" onclick="switchRoom(\''+value+'\')">' + value + '</a></center></div><hr>');
                    $("#chatlog-display-div").scrollTop($("#chatlog-display-div").prop("scrollHeight"));
                }
            });
        });
        function switchRoom(room){
            socket.emit('switchRoom', room);
        }

        $('form').submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          //right here is were i started changin it
          //gets the value from the message text feild and sets it as the    message var
          var message = {
            text : $('#chat-box-div-txtinpt').val()
          }
          if (message.text.trim().length !== 0) {
            socket.emit('chat-message', socket.username, message);
            //append the message to the chatlog-display-div
            $('#chat-box-div-txtinpt').focus().val('');
            jQuery("#chatlog-display-div").append('<div><b>'+socket.username+':</b>&nbsp'+message.text+'</div><hr>');
            $("#chatlog-display-div").scrollTop($("#chatlog-display-div").prop("scrollHeight"));
          }
        });

        socket.on('chat-message', function (user, message) {
          jQuery("#chatlog-display-div").append('<div><b>'+ user + ':</b>&nbsp'+message.text+'</div><hr>');
          $("#chatlog-display-div").scrollTop($("#chatlog-display-div").prop("scrollHeight"));
        });

      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Please tell me more about the problem. This code works nice for me. Let's find what's going on

Comment: sorry about that i was wondering if it is possible to put the code were it puts the users message into the div in the server.js that way the socket.username variable would be available.... if that makes any sense

Comment: thank you soo much sir it worked i tried it twice at first but i must have pasted it wrong because it was giving me a weird error thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

`socket.username` is undefined indeed (at the client side). I guess you defined `socket.username` at the server side but these two socket objects are not the same one. You could try this:

```
socket.on('connect', function(){
    var username = prompt("What's your name?");
    socket.username = username;
    socket.emit('adduser', username);
});
```

It may work ;)

Comment: thanks it works but it shows your name for every message as in 

I could set my name to steve then say hello all and it will show this on my window `STEVE: hello` and then somone else could set there name as bill and could say i am cool and it would show up like this on my screen `STEVE i am cool` and on there screen it would show `bill hello` and `bill i am cool` can you please help